# How to let the process inside a method finish running before return RepeatStatus.FINISHED? [Spring Batch]

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-batch

I have a Tasklet and my problem is that the process inside the selectAndProcessData() method **haven't finished** running but the log have stated that this tasklet have been funished.

Inside the method there is a query that need to extract quite amount of data from DB (about **450++** records) but in the end, only **100+** records was being printed out.

And the line before the RepeatStatus.FINISHED do not printed out before the tasklet has been finished.

How can I make the process inside selectAndProcessData() method **completely run** before letting the tasklet return **RepeatStatus.FINISHED**?

**My code:**

```
public class ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet implements Tasklet {

  private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
      selectAndProcessData();
      return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }

  private void selectAndProcessData(){

      String customerQuery = "select * from customers where age > 21";

      BeanPropertyRowMapper<Customer> beanPropertyRowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Customer.class);
      MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();

      List<Customer> customerList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(customerQuery, mapSqlParameterSource, beanPropertyRowMapper);
      log.info("customerList's size: " + customerList.size());

      if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(customerList)) {
          return;
      }
      Hashtable<String, Customer> customerHashtable = new Hashtable<>();
      for(Customers customer : customerList){
          if(!customerHashtable.containsKey(customer.getId())){
              customerHashtable.put(customer.getId(), customer);
              log.info("customer id: " + customer.getId());
          }else{
              log.info("customer id: " + customer.getId() + " not exist!");
          }

      }

      log.info("customerHashtable's size: " + customerHashtable.size()); //this line do not printed out
  }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
2022-10-05 21:25:25.987  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: 
[name=ExtractCustomerInfoJob]] launched with the following parameters: 
[{run.id=24}]
2022-10-05 21:25:26.103  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
c.f.b.j.c.listener.StartEndDateListener  : [start Date]:Tue Oct 04 
00:00:00 SGT 2022
2022-10-05 21:25:26.103  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
c.f.b.j.c.listener.StartEndDateListener  : [end Date]:Wed Oct 05 
00:00:00 SGT 2022
2022-10-05 21:25:26.103  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
c.f.batch.listener.ScheduleJobListener   : Start Schedule Job History 
Listener
2022-10-05 21:25:26.295  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
c.f.b.e.h.DefaultBatchEventHandler       : Extract_Customer_Info_Job is 
starting
2022-10-05 21:25:26.639  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [[1] Extract 
Customer Info from DB]
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customerList's size: 425
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0021011
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0084190
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0075917
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0068518
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0080279
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0073527
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0067744
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0078679
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0104133
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0043291
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0034689
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0097511
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0024483
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0059940
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0008263
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0132233
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0054388
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0108319
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0085711
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0136809
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0137462
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0038499
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0037966
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0137724
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0128406
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0137145
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0121859
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0111066
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0022478
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0046051
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0149903
2022-10-05 21:25:26.888  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
ExtractCustomerInfoTasklet : customer id: C0152974
2022-10-05 21:25:27.013  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [[1] Extract Customer 
Info from DB] executed in 1s404ms
2022-10-05 21:25:27.365  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
c.f.b.e.h.DefaultBatchEventHandler       : Extract_Customer_Info_Job has 
completed
2022-10-05 21:25:28.738  INFO 4944 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] 
o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: 
[name=Extract_Customer_Info_Job]] completed with the following 
parameters: [{run.id=24}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 
1s404ms
```

Comment: Execution won't return to the 'execute' method until 'selectAndProcessData' has completed. Can you paste the full class as you are returning a value in a void class which is a compilation error. Also what is the log output from the tasklet?

Comment: Why is this even a tasklet and not just a `JdbcCursorItemReader` with a processor/writer?

Comment: Hi @johnnyutts, just now accidentally returning a value in the void class. I have deleted that line and added in the logs output as well.

Comment: The code you have pasted is still not correct as there's no such method as containsKey on a List: - 'if(!customerList.containsKey(customer.getId())){'

Comment: Hi @johnnyutts, so sorry for that typo, I have edit the post with the updated code.